# Partially expanding a div to preview contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover over a div, I want another div (which starts as `display:none`) to partially expand downward, revealing only the top of its contents. How can I partially expand a hidden div with jQuery? Preferably so that the div fades out towards the bottom. There don't seem to be parameters for the `toggle()` command or `fadeIn()` that allow partial expansion.

## Edit

Unfortunately, the requirements don't allow a separate 'teaser' div to be used. The hidden div containing all the text has to be partially expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to only show the top 30 pixels of the hidden div:

```
var HowManyPixelsToShow = 30;

$(body).on({
   mouseenter: function() { ShowInfoBoxDiv($(this)); },
   mouseleave: HideInfoBoxes
}, '.info-box');

function ShowInfoBoxDiv(TheInfoBox) {
   //this assumes the 'more-info' divs are located after the '.info-box' divs
   TheInfoBox.next('.more-info') 
             .css('overflow':'hidden')
             .height(HowManyPixelsToShow)
             .slideDown(500);
}

function HideInfoBoxes() {
  $('.more-info').hide();
}
```

Comment: nah, I'm not in it for the 5 bucks:) I'm doing it for the fun! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

instead of toggling the entire div, separate the inner contents into a teaser div, and a content div, then toggle only the teaser div when you want a sneak peak

Comment: That's a great solution to the basic problem. Unfortunately, the specs don't allow for a separate preview div. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's animate function to show a preview. (open it a certain amount) Add a PNG with a transparent gradient to the bottom of that div to have it fade to white.
Start the #contentDiv with a height of 0px.

```
$("#hoverDiv").hover(
  function(){
    $("#contentDiv").animate({"height":"100px"});
  }, 
  function(){
    $("#contentDiv").animate({"height":"0px"});
  }
);
```